# Add to multiple strings the results from a tuple

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples

I'm trying to add to multiple strings the results from a tuple, in order:

```
   str1+=, str2+=, str3+=, params results() # return a tuple
```

Example:

```
str1 = 'alpha'
str2 = 'beta'
str3 = 'gama'

results() returns 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

So, the strings will become:

```
str1 ='alphaa'
str2 ='betab'
str3 = 'gamac'
```

This is not working. Can be done with using a `for loop` ?

Comment: No there is no way to do this, even in a for loop because strings are immutable (and for good reason!). This looks like poor code design, have a think about what you're trying to do an if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **vectorised** operations. This isn't possible in regular Python. But this is achievable, at least syntactically, via 3rd party libraries such as Pandas. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['alpha', 'beta', 'gama'])
s += ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(s.tolist())

['alphaa', 'betab', 'gamac']
```

With regular Python, you can use a list comprehension with `zip`. Python 3.6+ supports formatted string literals for simpler syntax:

```
str1 = 'alpha'
str2 = 'beta'
str3 = 'gama'

zipper = zip((str1, str2, str3), 'abc')
str1, str2, str3 = (f'{i}{suffix}' for i, suffix in zipper)

print(str1, str2, str3)

alphaa betab gamac
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must do what you're trying to do, the best solution I think is:

```
*strings, params = results()
str1 += strings[0]
str2 += strings[1]
str3 += strings[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do it with a for loop given the data types you are using because there is no way to iterate through your string variables. you would need for them to be elements in a list of strings.

given your current setup this is what you could use

```
str1+=results[0]
str2+=results[1]
str3+=results[3]
params=results[4]
```

to have a for loop you would use this

```
str_list = [str1,str2,str3,params]

for item in results:
    if results.index(item) < 3:
        str_list[results.index(item)]+=item
    else:
        str_list[results.index(item)]=item
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will do what you want to do:

```
strings = ["hello", "world"] // string you want to be extended
new_strings = [e[0] + e[1] for e in zip(strings, results())]
```

`new_strings` will contain the strings extended with values in the output of `result()`